# Getting Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1) in flutter API response

Tags: android, flutter, dart, httprequest

I am newbie to Flutter. I am making POST API call and on which I am expecting response like {"status":"Saved"} as I am getting this properly in Postman, but I am getting Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1) in my flutter code. I checked similar questions and answers on stack overflow but none of it helped me.

```
static Future<SaveLocationData> saveLocation(BuildContext context, String url,
      {Map body}) async {
    print("save location pressed $body");

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
    try {
      return post(url, body: jsonEncode(body), headers: requestHeaders)
          .then((response) {


        print("DATA ${response.body}");

        var parsedJson = json.decode(response.body.toString());
        NormalAlert.showAlert(
            context,
            "${parsedJson['status'].toString().replaceAll("\n", " ")}",
            "Save Location");

        final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
        if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
          throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
        }
        return SaveLocationData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print("erroris $error");
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is displayed by "print ("DATA $ {response.body}");".

Comment: Getting o/p as : DATA 
Nothing after that. I am expecting {"status":"Saved"} as a response as in postman

Comment: What is the status code?

Comment: I think we need to judge the status code first.

Comment: I am getting only {"status":"Saved"} in json response nothing else.

Comment: I mean "response.statusCode". What is the "response.statusCode"?

Comment: I think we need to judge the "response.statusCode" first.

Comment: What if Response object does not have statusCode?

Comment: Normally, I think HTTP requests have a status code. [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)
For more information, please see the specification of the URL you requested.

Comment: I am getting 401 in response. But the request is working properly in postman

Comment: @YuuWoods thank you for the help. It was authorisation issue, through status code able to find that